# Can inline range hood exhaust fan damper be safely/legally installed,1st floor of 2 story apt

Tags: exhaust-vent, range, hood

I live in a 2 story apartment.  Whenever the tenants directly upstairs turn on their range hood exhaust fan, I get whatever they are cooking/burning in my apartment.  I have pulled down the range hood and there is no inline  damper.
1.  Can an in-line damper be installed safely and legally (fire code?)
2.  Is it possible past landlords (It's almost 60 yrs old) replaced range hoods (this range hood is about 8 yrs old) and INTENTIONALLY left out damper to save on maintenance/insurance costs?
3.  Is it possible that the entire exhaust system for both upper and lower kitchens is designed to work without in-line dampers, and there is another problem in the system.  (Clogged at the roof? Single in-line damper upstairs missing/defective?)

PS.  The last landlord suggested putting in a new range hood with a simple air return back into the kitchen (which is probably illegal.)  The new landlord's super suggested I simply turn on my exhaust fan when I start to smell something. (What I've been doing for the last six years except when I'm not home). I'm kinda on my own.

Comment: I am not sure of any code that would prevent you from installing a damper. As far as I know current code requires individual dampers.

Comment: Are these ranges gas or electric?

Comment: It is a gas range

Comment: It's possible that it's an illegal install where someone ducted a range hood into a common exhaust duct designed for general kitchen exhaust ventilation, but not range exhausting. Because I can't think of any legal install that uses a shared duct without a common exhaust fan running to extract from the roof (or wherever it ends), and certainly no range hood install into a common duct without a damper, let alone without the friggin common exhausting fan. If the landlord is this clueless, it's probably also a greasy fire hazard.